# Why is it better to have the private key as the multiplicative inverse mod phi(n) in RSA?

Tags: rsa

I'm studying the RSA algorithm and the theory says to select $d$ to be the multiplicative inverse of.

$$
e \mod \phi(n) 
$$

If we take this approach I know that it is important that $e$ and  $\phi(n)$ are coprime.

Why is this "better" as opposed to say the following equation where $e$ is still selected as a coprime to $\phi(n)$:

$$
 d = \frac{\phi(n) + 1}{e}
$$

I would like to have a deep explanation. I do not have formal math training, so any links to help understand the answer is very much appreciated.

Comment: It is very unlikely that (phi(n)+1)/e is an integer.

Comment: What problems will d not being an integer cause from a practical or a theoretical perspective?

Comment: @IshanAntony Now you need to define what modular exponentiation with a fractional exponent is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

In the standarized RSA algorithm the private key $d$ is calculated computing the modular multiplicative inverse with the Extended Euclidean GCD that satisfies:

$1\equiv e \cdot d\pmod {\varphi(p \cdot q})$

Notice that modular multiplicative inverse can be expressed as:

$$d=\frac{\varphi(p\cdot q)\cdot k + 1}{e}$$

for some $k$ multiple of $\varphi$($p\cdot q$). We know that $e$ is 17 bits (65537) so $k$ will be small, thus computing $d$ with this method would be realizable. You have to know the factorization of the semiprime for computing $\varphi(p \cdot q)$.

Mathematically other ways for computing the private key exist, such as the Euler Criterion.

For calculating the modular multiplicative inverse we would have:

$d\equiv e^{\varphi(\varphi(p \cdot q))-1}\pmod {\varphi(p \cdot q})$

As you can see we would need to have the factorization of $\varphi(p\cdot q)$, so we cannot deal with big semiprime modulus. Concretely we need the factors of $(p-1)$ and $(q-1)$ in order to compute $\varphi(p-1) \cdot \varphi(q-1)$

Comment: Comments on my question more directly answered my question.. which is we need the private key to be an integer and that modular multiplicative inverse is a guaranteed way to achieve it.. notice that I asked why is the standard way better

Comment: @kub0x: Modular inverses are easily obtained from extended Euclidean algorithm.  There is no need to know $\varphi(p-1)$ or $\varphi(q-1)$.

Comment: @user94293: If you take a closer look to the beginning of my post you will see that I mention the Extended euclidean as the standard algorithm. I just have given more methods, like Euler's.. you know, more information more knowledge ;)

Comment: @kub0x The method you present is not practical for concrete implementations of RSA as for a $2048$-bit RSA modulus, it requires factoring two $1024$-bit integers.  Efficient methods not relying of the extended Euclidean algorithm for computing modular inverses can be found in [ Joye and Paillier, CHES 2003, http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-45238-6_20 ].

Comment: @user94293: Yes, you are right on that. At the bottom of the post I explained that you have to factor the modulus totient. I just wanted to give a different mathematical approach, but pointing the Extended Euclidean as the recommended. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The number $1$ is known as the multiplicative identity.

In RSA, $d$ is the multiplicative inverse of $e$, therefore, $ed=1$. Mathematically $d$ would normally be a fraction, such as, $e=4$, then $d={1\over 4}$, thereby $4\cdot {1\over 4}=1$. RSA uses modular rings, so we compute $d$ as a modular multiplicative inverse of $e$, then $d\equiv e^{-1}\bmod \varphi(p\cdot q)$ (for textbook RSA), resulting in $1\equiv ed\bmod \varphi(p\cdot q)$.

Now if we round-robin a message, $C=M^e\bmod(p\cdot q)$, then $M'=C^d\bmod(p\cdot q)$, we get $M'=M$, the original message. If we do a little substitution, we have $M'=(M^e)^d=M^{ed}=M^1$, which we know is equivalent  to $M'=M$ because any positive number to the power of $1$ equals itself, as in, $438^1=438$.

Given the equations $d\equiv e^{-1}\bmod \varphi(p\cdot q)$ and $d={{\varphi(p\cdot q) \cdot k+1}\over e}$, both require knowledge of $p$ and $q$, however, the second requires also finding a value for $k$ which produces an integer result. This is more challenging for larger $(p\cdot q)$ than performing the modular multiplicative inverse function.